# Cannot add SQLite plugin to intel xdk, shows missing sqlite-connector.jar file

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

When i try to add [this](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git) plugin to my project in Intel Xdk using third party plugin add option, its shows misssing jar file.

error:
projectname\plugins\cordova-sqlite-storage\node_modules\cordova-sqlite-storage-dependencies\libs\sqlite-connector.jar" not found!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the [link](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git) to the Intel XDK third party plugin. Before that please download the project dependency jar file from [github](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage-dependencies) and create the directory with cordova plugin SQLite name and place the file in it, include the jar file. Then try to add the plugin using URL .

Hope all working well